# React native view transform scale

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, toggle

I am having some trouble with basic view transformation.

https://snack.expo.dev/@innoware/transforms

Try clicking the "toggle" button, the scale will toggle between 1 to 2.

Why does the blue view not scale around its top left corner?